# Angular IE8 attrs.$set / element.attr don't work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I transform my own tag into input.
I can choose readonly / disable for input using select.
I did it. It works. But not in ie8 )).

I read official docs for Angular and IE8.
I added it. But my app doesn't work in ie8.

I can't add readonly / disabled attributes (readonly="readonly" and disabled="disabled")

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TSQLb3nmdq3emqcUMTzx?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="dir">
<head>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>

    <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Internet Explorer AngularJS element creation -->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script>
        document.createElement('dhtmlxdate');
    </script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.2.4/json3.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>ie8</title>

</head>
<body>

<tag mode="{{mode}}"></tag>

<select ng-model="mode">
    <option>disabled</option>
    <option>readonly</option>
</select>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var myapp = angular.module("dir", []);
    myapp.directive('tag', function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: false,
      template: '<input type="text" />'
        ,

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            attrs.$observe('mode', function(value) {
                switch(value) {
                    case "disabled":
                        //attrs.$set('disabled', 'disabled');
                        element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        element.removeAttr('readonly');
                        break;
                    case "readonly":
                        //attrs.$set('readonly', 'readonly');
                        element.attr('readonly', 'readonly');
                        element.removeAttr('disabled');
                        break;
                }
            });

        }
            };
        }); 

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't use attr to set the disabled/readonly properties. Use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead.

Comment: I use element.prop('type', 'text'); I use element.prop('readonly', 'readonly'); I use element.prop('readonly', true); All of this don't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want to save yourself from having huge headaches in the future, especially if you need IE support, it's best advised for you to manually bootstrap your Angular application like this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['yourAppName']);
});
```

As for your actual question, both 'readonly' and 'disabled' attributes are **Boolean Attributes**, that means you don't have to set a value to them `cause as long as they are present on the element, they will take effect.

That said, if you want to conditionally set them on your input, I suggest you use [ngReadonly](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly) and [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled%20%22%22)

Working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/zEmA0AjJB5AoonLKCM7C

Comment: No. IE8 doesn't work. I added `ng-disabled="disabled" ng-readonly="readonly"` to input. And included `scope.disabled = 'true'; scope.readonly = '';` in switch. Works in all browsers except IE.

Comment: I don't have IE8 on this machine, please try this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/zEmA0AjJB5AoonLKCM7C

Comment: You're lucky man (about ie8)! It works! And why does angular.bootstrap(docu... add empty string in select?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I don't understand what do you mean by that

Comment: add your `angular.element(document).ready(function() {...` in your last example and click select. You will see 3 lines: '', readonly, disabled.

Comment: Ah! Since "mode" doesn't exist on the current scope, and the input is doble-bound to it, the current value for "mode" would be "null" and the input displays a "null" option.
Try and add `ng-init="mode = 'disabled'` to the body (or to your controller)

Comment: Now I need add type='hidden'. It's incorrect in IE8. I typed `element.attr('type', 'hidden');` It works everywhere except ie8. or `element.css("visibility", "hidden");` not `display: none`